# In Hive, how to properly use get_json_object to extract value when there is a `$` sign in the path

Tags: json, hive, dollar-sign

```
value
{"$screen_width":375,"$app_version":"2.5.0"}
```

Suppose I have a table shown above. The value `"2.5.0"` is what I want. 
I try to use `get_json_object` but it fails.
Because the path `"$app_version"` includes a `$` sign and Hive treats it as a root directory sign.

I try several code ways but all fail and return `NULL`.

```
select get_json_object(value,"$.$app_version")
select get_json_object(value,"$.\\$app_version")
select get_json_object(value,"$.\$app_version")
select get_json_object(value,"$..app_version")
```

Any advanced Hive users knows to fix it?

Temporally, I use regular expression to solve it.

```
select 
    regexp_extract(
        properties
        ,'\\"\\$os_version\\":\\"[\\d?]+\\.[\\d?]+\\.[\\d?]+\\"'
        ,0
    )
    ,properties
from opd.test_json_object
```

However, I am curious there is no chance to use `get_json_object` here?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to get directly the value with the `$` sign, but usually, you should consider `lateral view` with `json_tuple` (see [doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-json_tuple)) instead of `get_json_object`. Performance wise it's much faster and I personally like the fact that json columns become 'normal' columns.

For your example, I would suggest the following:

```
-- CTE to simulate a temporary table
with json as (
  select '{"$screen_width":375,"$app_version":"2.5.0"} ' as value
)
-- actual query
select *
from json 
lateral view 
  json_tuple(value, "$screen_width", "$app_version") lv as 
    screen_width, app_version;
```

The result is:

```
+------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|                   json.value                   | lv.screen_width  | lv.app_version  |
+------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------+
| {"$screen_width":375,"$app_version":"2.5.0"}   | 375              | 2.5.0           |
+------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

So you can now just use `lv.app_version` in your `select` statement (instead of my `*`) to get the value you are looking for.

Comment: quick reply and great help. Thanks.